# In a text file with linked structures, how do I quickly follow those links in C++, without running through the file multiple times?

Tags: c++, search, ifc

I'm about to start a project that requires me to load specific information from an IFC file into classes or structs. I'm using C++, but it's been some years since I last used it so I'm a bit rusty.

The IFC file has a linked structure, where an element in a line might refer to a different line, which in turn links to another. I've included a short example where the initial "#xxx" is the line index and any other "#xxx" in the line is a link to a different line.

```
#170=IFCAXIS2PLACEMENT3D(#168,$,$);
#171=IFCLOCALPLACEMENT(#32,#170);
#172=IFCBUILDINGSTOREY("GlobalId", #41, "Name", "Description", "ObjectType", #171"...);
```

In this example I would need to search for "IFCBULDINGSTOREY", and then follow the links backwards through the file, jumping around storing the important bits of information I need.

The main problem is that my test file has 273480 lines (18MB), and links can jump from one end of the file to the other - and I'll likely have to handle larger files than this.

In this file I need to populate about 500 objects, so that's a lot of jumping around the file to grap the relevant information.

What's a performance-friendly method of jumping around a file like that?

Comment: Load that file into memory.  How big are files normally?  Also look at unit testing.

Comment: Why not [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) with the first line number as keys and then the value as either a [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) holding the string and referred to line as the value (or you could use a plain old `struct` for the value) That way the first line number is the unique key that is associated with the referred to line (and if needed the whole string). That would allow you to locate a line and quickly jump to the referred to line object.

Comment: @gramam: I don't know much about the average file size yet unfortunately but I don't expect them to exceed 100MB. The buildings I'm preparing for aren't ready yet.

Comment: @David: Thanks, I'll test that and see how it performs

Comment: For something like this I'd search the net for [IFC classes c++](https://www.google.com/search?q=IFC+classes+c%2B%2B) and see if someone haven't created something handling this already.

Comment: @Ted: I've searched, but the libraries that exist have wildly different purposes and doesn't suit my project very well.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclosure - I help out with a [.NET IFC implementation](https://github.com/xBimTeam))

I'd question what it is you're doing that means you can't use one of the [many](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/collection/ifc-sdk/solution/ifc-sdk?f%5B0%5D=solution_content_bundle%3Aasset_release) [existing](https://github.com/ifcquery/ifcplusplus) implementations of the IFC schema. Parsing the IFC models is generally the simple part of the problem. If you want to visualise the geometry or take measurements from the geometry primitives there's a whole another level of complexity... E.g. Just one particular geometry type out of dozens: https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC4_3/RC2/HTML/link/ifcadvancedbrep.htm

If you go to [BuildingSmart's software implementations list](https://technical.buildingsmart.org/resources/software-implementations/) and search for 'development' you'll get a good list of them for various technologies/languages.

If you're sure you want to implement yourself, the typical approaches are to build some kind of dictionary/map holding the entities based on their key. Naively you can run an initial pass through with a Lexer, and build the map in memory. But as IFC models can be over a GB, you may need a more sophisticated approach where you build some kind of persisted index - and maybe even put it into some kind of database with indexes (maybe some flavour of a document database). This is going to be more important if you want to support 'random access' to the data over multiple sessions.

Comment: Thank you. However I only need to extract a fraction of information, which is why I found using a library to be overkill.

Comment: The issue with that is IFC is all about the relationships. So even though you 'only need a fraction' of the information, you're going to be following long chains of these relationships to get the data you want. e.g. if you wanted the properties of the building story, or the material of a component it's often 4-5 links away - semi-randomly over the file.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but all the libraries I've found are about visualizing the data. All I need to do is move certain data from a finite number of IFC files into a database once per file. So my implementation doesn't have to be the most efficient solution, as long as it's faster than doing it manually - which it will be almost no matter how poorly my program performs.